# how to access a object of two words in html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
Person = {
  first Name = ["ABC", "XYZ"]
}
```

In ngFor I want to iterate over 'first Name'

I tried `*ngFor="let person of Person['first Name']` but this is not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean `Person = { "first Name": ["ABC", "XYZ"]}` ?  What you have is a syntax error.

Comment: if you defined the `Person` Object like this, it's wrong. should be `'first Name' : ['ABC']` - not `first Name = ['ABC']` - Also can you include more of your template html in your question ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sunset-22c01?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your object like that:

```
let person = {'first Name': ["ABC", "XYZ"]}
```

Then try to iterate like that:

```
*ngFor="let person of Person['first Name']"
```

Comment: Object keys can have spaces , see here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @PascalLamers thanks for the great comment! I've edited the reply!

Comment: Maybe add another " at the end 

Answer (score -4):

*ngFor="let person of Person.first_Name"
Also,
Make sure your JSON is formatted correctly.

for Example:
Person = {first_Name : ["ABC", "XYZ"]}

Comment: I am sure it's a javascript object we are dealing with, and objects can have spaces in keys : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects